# Change Document Class in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex, lilypond

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX with lilypond and lilypond-book. The first part of the document is just musical examples and for that, the document class {book} suffices. The second part, however, needs to follow the conventions of stage.cls . I was wondering if it is possible to change document classes at that section. I have tried to include the PDF file of the part of the document that uses stage but it ruins the table of contents at the front of my thesis, and it also restarts page numbering.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that [questions about *programming* in tex or latex *are* on-topic on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12918/2509), though you might prefer to use the specialty site simply because your question will come to the attention of experts there. That said, it is not clear that *this* question has the programing nature.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing a somewhat similar problem and while I have not come to the point where I need to implement the solution I have done some research in preparation. The most helpful is the following [multidoc FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multidoc) from TeX. Hope that can at least steer you in the right direction.